# SQL programming for Calculating Failure Rate

Tags: sql

```
+------+------+
|DealId|Failcode|
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
```

I would like to select the DealId that occurs more than once with the different Failcode And their failurerate

The output should be something like:

```
+------+------+-----+
|DealId|Fail  |count|
+------+------+-----+
|1     |A     |3    |
+------+------+-----+
|1     |B     |1    |
+------+------+-----+
|2     |A     |2    |
+------+------+-----+
|2     |B     |1    |
+------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

use aggregation and `group by`

```
select DealId,Fail,count(*) as cnt
from tablename
group by DealId,Fail
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE EXIST` like following to check `DealId` that occurs more than once with the different `Failcode` .

To show the count, you can simply use `GROUP BY dealid,failcode`

```
SELECT T1.dealid, 
       T1.failcode Fail, 
       Count(*)    AS CT 
FROM   YourTableName T1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   YourTableName T2 
               WHERE  T2.dealid = T1.dealid 
                      AND T2.failcode <> T1.failcode) 
GROUP  BY T1.dealid, 
          T1.failcode
```

**Note**: Replace `YourTableName` with actual table name.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I will try it out to check whether its working or not

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to select the DealId that occurs more than once with the different Failcode And their failurerate

I interpret this as saying that you want more than one type of failure rate.  Your sample data doesn't provide any example of deal ids that are filtered out by the first condition.  But the answer to this question appears to be:

```
select dealid, fail, cnt
from (select DealId, Fail, count(*) as cnt,
             count(*) over (partition by DealId) as cnt_fails
      from tablename
      group by DealId, Fail
     ) t
having cnt_fails > 1;
```